# MySQL 8.0.11 error connect to caching_sha2_password the specified module could not be found

Tags: mysql, plugins, mysql-workbench

I've tried to connect to the latest MySQL server 8.0.11 from MySQL workbench, but the error keeps popping up: Cannot connect to MySQL server, authentication plugin: caching_sha2_password: the specified module could not be found.

I tried looking at MySQL server installation videos online and replicated every step accurately, but the error persists.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I had the following solution:
change *my.ini* in a `[mysqld]` section like this:

```
#default_authentication_plugin=caching_sha2_password  (comment line!)
default_authentication_plugin=mysql_native_password   (new line)
```

Connect to your MySQL under root in a command line client
and execute:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'xxx';
```

Where `xxx` is your current password.

Comment: One amendment, I had to change `... BY 'xxx'` to what I'd like my *new* password to be, rather than what my previous password was.

Comment: This will revert to the old password hashing system and is strongly disrecommended

Comment: **FYI:** `my.ini` is AKA `my.cnf`.

Answer (score 25):

Try to connect your MySQL use terminal, and use this.

```
mysql > ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'yourpassword';
```

Comment: Thanks!!! Work for me! macOS 10.13.5 + MySQL 8 (mysql  Ver 8.0.11 for osx10.13 on x86_64 (Homebrew))

Comment: Error Code: 1396. Operation ALTER USER failed for 'azhar'@'localhost'

Answer (score 3):

See:

> [Changes in MySQL Workbench 8.0.11 (2018-04-19, Release
>   Candidate)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/workbench/en/wb-news-8-0-11.html)
>
> ...
>
> - MySQL Workbench now supports the caching_sha2_password authentication plugin introduced in MySQL 8.0 (see [Caching SHA-2 Pluggable Authentication](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/caching-sha2-pluggable-authentication.html)). A user account can be reset to use the other available authentication types for making a connection.
>
> ...

Comment: The release candidate is indeed the way to go. You can download it from the "Development Releases" tab on the Workbench download page.

Answer (score 2):

After poking around I actually found a way to solve it:

During the configuration, when you reach the authentication method choose the Legacy Authentication Method.

It worked for me~!

Answer (score 2):

I was seeing this issue with HeidiSQL, and I found a workaround in the HeidiSQL Github repository:

https://github.com/HeidiSQL/HeidiSQL/issues/163

I fixed by copying libmysql.dll from my last MySql install to my HeidiSQL folder.

Comment: It worked when I delete `libmariadb.dll` file from HeidiSQL folder as well as updated `libmysql.dll` from MySQL lib folder.

Answer (score 1):

If you have just installed mysql server. Run the installer again and it will allow you to reconfigure the options.
On the third sceen it will say
"Use legacy Authentication method"
choose that option

Answer (score 1):

I know it is an old post. This is just to share my experience, hoping it will be useful for someone.
I also faced similar issue. 
We can use the portable version of Heidisql. The portable version does not have this issue.

Answer (score 1):

**using mysql_native_password is a workaround.**

Your client software (MySQL Workbench) does not support the authentication plugin most probably because it is an older version.

https://tableplus.io/blog/2018/07/failed-to-load-caching-sha2-password-authentication-plugin-solved.html

follow the above link.

Answer (score 0):

The actual reason for "caching_sha2_password" is because while installing MySQL under Authentication Method, by default *Use Strong Crypted Password* radio button is chosen, instead we need to give *User Legacy Authentication type* password option for password

Run this in MySQL WorkBench:

```
ALTER USER 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';
```

Then further edit the credential and schema to access under the below directory path:

```
ror_project_path/config/database.yml
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using DBeaver and getting this error when importing / restoring a database, then there is a good chance its because your DBeaver needs to be updated.

Once updated, this error went away.