# Issue with authentication plugin for MySQL Enterprise Edition

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have installed a trial of the MySQL Enterprise Edition and when connecting using the bundled Workbench software i get the following error:

Authentication plugin caching_sha2_password cannot be loaded: The specified module cannot be found

About which there i can find very little information. Most solutions return to the old authentication method, but I don't want to do that, and it doesn't seem to work anyway...

HeidiSQL gives the same error message.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL 8.0.11 error connect to caching\_sha2\_password the specified module could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50169576/mysql-8-0-11-error-connect-to-caching-sha2-password-the-specified-module-could-n)

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround in the HeidiSQL Github repository:

https://github.com/HeidiSQL/HeidiSQL/issues/163

I fixed by copying libmysql.dll from my last MySql install to my HeidiSQL folder.