# Mysql 8 remote access

Tags: mysql, authentication, mysql-8.0

I usualy setup correctly MySQL for having remote access.

And currently I got stuck with MySQL 8.

The first thing is that on the mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf , I don't have any bind-address line, so I added it by hand (bind-address 0.0.0.0)
And I granted access to the user on '%'

When I connected I got the message "Authentication failed"

But it works well on localhost/command line

Comment: I think you have to comment the bind address and give the permission on '%' from root.

Comment: You might be having trouble because MySQL 8 changed the default authentication plugin, and some clients need to be upgraded. An alternative is to configure your MySQL 8 instance to use the traditional  mysql_native_password plugin. It's hard to know for sure because you have given no details about how you're connecting (client, language, etc.) Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/upgrading-from-previous-series.html#upgrade-caching-sha2-password

Comment: I gave permission on root with Host = '%' 
I tried to connect with dbForge Studio (a database client) from my 
computer. 
I also read the upgrate updates to MySQL 8 I do not see anything dealing with remote access updgrade

Comment: ok I updated to old autentication system, and now I got as error : "This server version 8.0.11 is not currently supported."
Im checking with Dbforge

Answer (score 62):

1. Delete or comment the `bind_address` parameter from the `my.ini` file.

> (The file name is different depend on the OS. On Linux my.ini is
>   actually my.cnf located in directory /etc/mysql/)

2. Restart the service.
3. Create the `root` user (**yes, a new user** because what exists is 'root@localhost' which is local access only):

   `CREATE USER 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '123';`
4. Give the privileges:

   `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%';`

> For *DBA* user, add `WITH GRANT OPTION` at the end.
>
> e.g. `CREATE USER 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '123' WITH GRANT OPTION;`

---

*Because it does not work **CREATE with GRANT**?*

*MySQL 8* can no longer create a user with `GRANT`, so there is an error in `IDENTIFIED BY '123'` if you try to use it with `GRANT`, which is the most common error.

Comment: This works just fine, thanks for sharing your response.

Comment: Thanks it worked. But the file name is different depend on the OS. On Linux `my.ini` is actually `my.cnf` located in directory `/etc/mysql/`.

Comment: @EvanHu It's true. I had forgotten that.
I will include in the answer to be more complete and help others. Thanks!

Comment: Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' cannot be loaded: The specified module could not be found.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50169576/mysql-8-0-11-error-connect-to-caching-sha2-password-the-specified-module-could-n

Comment: I think there's a mistake in the answer. The `WITH GRANT OPTION` clause is not applicable to `CREATE USER` statement, but to `GRANT` statement

Comment: @malloc4k Yes, it's at the end of the answer.  :)

Comment: If you see any error such as ```ERROR 1396```, then just change ```root``` to any other ```remoteuser```, it will work perfect!

Comment: perfect answer .....

Comment: thanks for the tip that root users differ from host to host in mysql v8 ... thanks u saved my day

Answer (score 25):

**Remote Access in MySQL 8:**

**1) Allow access from any host**

```
sudo nano /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf

bind-address            = 0.0.0.0
```

**2) Allow the user to access from anywhere:**

```
mysql

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%';
UPDATE mysql.user SET host='%' WHERE user='root';
```

**3) Change authentication to password**

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'ThePassword';
```

Comment: Except you would not want to do this to the `root` account, it just opens up another attack vector. Create a new account that only has access to what it needs, rather than using the SUPER User

Comment: @DivinesLight why my answer is incorret?

Comment: You probably need a 'root'@'%' to start with.

Answer (score 15):

Had the same problem, Connected to MySQL Workbench and updated the User privilege.

MySQL version : 8.0.20 Community.
OS : Windows 10.

1. Open MySQL Workbench --> Server --> Users and Privileges
2. Select the user
3. Change the Limit to Hosts Matching to "%" for accessing from any host.
4. Apply changes.
5. Restart MySQL Service if required. It worked for me with out restarting.

Screen shot,
[image: MySQL Workbench 8.0.20]

Comment: This is perfect and best solution for MySQL 8. Forgot everything about bind_address or bind-address and apply this trick.

Comment: This worked and was done in 2 minutes. I was looknig for mysql.ini in 8, but then found this.

Answer (score 3):

For MySQL 8 open the mysqld.cnf file

```
sudo nano /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
```

And modify or add the **bind-address** option:

```
[mysqld]
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
```

Restart the **mysql** server

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

Comment: In manual 8.0, change *bind-address* to *bind_address* [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/ipv6-remote-connections.html)

Comment: Forget about adding anything additional to the cnf file, don't add "bind-address" or "bind_address". The correct solution is to grant the root user (or another user) remote access since root comes only with localhost access:

sudo mysql -u root -p
# CREATE USER 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '1234567890';
# GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%';

sudo systemctl restart mysql

Comment: GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%';

Answer (score 0):

Mysql 8: Following solution worked for me:

- Change bind-address from 127.0.0.1 to 0.0.0.0

```
    vim /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
```

- Sign in to your mysql using root and then:

```
    CREATE USER 'docker'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'your_password_here'; 
    
    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'docker'@'%';
```