# unable to connect to mysql running inside WSL

Tags: mysql, windows-subsystem-for-linux

[image]

Getting the above error while connecting to mysql server running on WSL. That's weird 
because I have done this with postgresql and it worked fine.

But if on the WSL command prompt I type `mysql -u root` I am able to connect to it.
The Dbeaver or any other window client application or any java program is also giving error

Comment: What is running where?

Comment: windows subsystem for linux

Comment: I know what WSL is @nbk. I was wondering where the database was running and where these client tools were running

Comment: You have to allow remote access, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50570592/mysql-8-remote-access

Comment: or take a look https://askubuntu.com/questions/1249973/connect-mysql-workbench-to-wsl2

Comment: database is running on WSL. And client tools on windows

Comment: I noticed that I could login from WSL only when I run the command - `sudo mysqld --skip-grant-tables &` and then start the mysql otherwise even from inside mysql I get access denied error

Comment: Networking works different on WSL1 and WSL2. If you are using WSL2, the Linux will have a different IP address and you may require some additional configuration. -- Are you running MySQL on WSL2?  What is the ip address assigned to the Linux?