# Django database authentication plugin error

Tags: python, mysql, django

I had a Django project that I had worked on in the past for quite a while. Recently, I tried to reopen it and add some minor changes. What happened is that recently I also reinstalled MySQL(8.0) and of course, recreated my old database. But now when I tried to run the server or any other operation, I get the following error:

```html
2059, "Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' cannot be loaded: The specified module could not be found.
```

I tried the solution from other post, but it did not work for me. Here is also a full traceback of the error: https://pastebin.com/JqexqTtC

Comment: What did you try? alter user to mysql_native_password ?

Comment: Yes, didn't work for me

Comment: try updating your mysql connector library / libmysqlclient-dev. *Starting with MySQL 8.0.4, we are changing the default authentication plugin for MySQL server from mysql_native_password to caching_sha2_password. Correspondingly, libmysqlclient will now use caching_sha2_password as the default authentication mechanism, too*.

Comment: @Mate thank you for the guidance! The third answer of this question, was the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50169576/mysql-8-0-11-error-connect-to-caching-sha2-password-the-specified-module-could-n

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I fix this issue with the first method:

1. If you have access to database through workbench, mysql console... and you have permission to alter user so you can change auth_plugin for default

   ALTER  USER 'your_user' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'your_password';
2. If you don't have permission to it database so you can change mysql connector.

add link: https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/sql/raise+errors.NotSupportedError%28+mysql.connector.errors.NotSupportedError%3A+Authentication+plugin+%27caching_sha2_password%27+is+not+supported