# Django+MySQL - "Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' cannot be loaded"

Tags: python, mysql, django, python-3.x, mysql-connector

When running the command: `python manage.py runserver` I'm getting the following error:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2059, "Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' cannot be loaded: The specified module could not be found.\r\n")
```

These are the relevant settings:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'polls',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '<my-password>',
        'HOST': 'localhost'
    }
}
```

I've seen solutions that went around the problem, such as in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54633968/2059-authentication-plugin-caching-sha2-password-when-running-server-conne). They suggest changing the engine to `mysql.connector.django`, however the engine recommended by django is `mysqlclient` and therefore I would like to use it.
Other suggestion were to [use naive password instead of sha2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50169576/mysql-8-0-11-error-connect-to-caching-sha2-password-the-specified-module-could-n). I'd rather not go with this solution for security reasons.

Versions:

- mysql 8.0.17 for Win64 on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)
- python 3.7.4
- Django 2.2.4
- mysqlclient 1.4.4

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY '<my-password>';
```

Comment: This doesn't address the original question.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my question. However, I specified in the question that I'd rather not go with a native password solution for security reasons (see the last paragraph).